# What is the best way to make a fighter companion more effective at healing me in combat?

Tags: dnd-5e, fighter, healing

I'm playing in a campaign with a level 5 Ranger at the moment. After a large battle, we looted an armory and acquired among other things a "Deck of Many Things".

My character ended up drawing a card that mysteriously employs a knight (level 4 fighter) in your service. He/she is sworn to protect you and is under complete control by the player who drew the card.

Here's my question, assuming my DM would allow it at all.

I want my fighter companion to be able to heal me in combat or at least stabilize me without having to make a medicine check.

1. If given the option should I multi-class her into Paladin, or
   Cleric?
2. Should I multi-class her at all?
3. What would be the best way to make
       her a proficient healer?

   We're a bit fuzzy on her actual stats for the moment. We didn't make a character sheet for her yet. I plan on doing that tonight.

Bottom line, I want to make it easier for my level 4 fighter companion to heal other PCs in combat or stabilize them if they reach 0 HP.  What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Bottom line, I want to make it easier for my level 4 fighter companion to heal other PCs in combat or **stabilize them if they reach 0 HP**. How should I go about that?

This part is easy: give them a Healer's Kit. That lets anyone stabilize another character without having to make a check, and it only costs 5gp.

Beyond that, if you want to multi-class to get as much healing as possible, your best bet is to go Cleric with the Life domain. The Cleric has full spell-casting slots and the largest number of supporting and healing spells, and the Life Domain makes your healing spells even better.

Comment: In addition, if the Fighter takes the Healer feat (assuming the DM allows players to choose feats instead of ASIs), they can use it to heal people as an action as well.

Comment: There's a tradeoff here: if you want the best actual *healing*, yes, cleric with Life domain is the way to go. But if all you're concerned about is stabilizing during a fight, for example if you have few hit points and get knocked out multiple times per fight, the flexibility of the Death Domain cleric (if allowed) as in Nick Brown's answer, or the paladin's ability to use Lay on Hands one hit point at a time to get people up and back in the fight, can't be beat.

Comment: @SirTechSpec you mean *grave* domain, not death!

Comment: @Carcer Correct, slip of the keyboad!

Answer (score 12):

### Combat Medic / Shield Maiden build

Here are some options your fighter has to make it more of a supporting healer.

### 3 Feats to choose from:

If your fighter is a level 4 variant human, she'll have access to 2 feats. One at level 1 and another at level 4.

If she is a variant human that multiclassed before reaching level 4 *or* a level 4 fighter of another race, you'll have 1 feat. This assumes you did not pick ASI at level 4. Any other combination leaves you without access to feats.

Choose up to as many as you have access to:

> **Inspiring Leader**
>
> Prerequisite: Charisma 13 or higher
>
> You can spend 10 minutes inspiring your companions, shoring up their
> resolve to fight. When you do so, choose up to six friendly creatures
> (which can include yourself) within 30 feet of you who can see or hear
> you and who can understand you.
>
> Each creature can gain temporary hit points equal to your level + your
> Charisma modifier. A creature can't gain temporary hit points from
> this feat again until it has finished a short or long rest.

Inspiring leader allows you to buff your team with temporary hit points once per short rest. Having temporary hit points before the start of an encounter is always nice to have.

> **Healer**
>
> You are an able physician, allowing you to mend wounds quickly and get your allies back in the fight.
>
> You gain the following benefits:
> When you use a healer’s kit to stabilize a dying creature, that
> creature also regains 1 hit point.
>
> As an action, you can spend one use of a healer’s kit to tend to a creature and restore 1d6 + 4 hit points
> to it, plus additional hit points equal to the creature’s maximum
> number of Hit Dice. The creature can’t regain hit points from this
> feat again until it finishes a short or long rest.

The healer feat with the healer's kit allows you to restore a creature's hit points once until the next short or long rest. This is a cheap way to heal without magic but is very limited in application.

> **Magic Initiate (Cleric)**
>
> Choose a class: bard, cleric, druid, sorcerer, warlock, or wizard.
>
> You learn two cantrips of your choice from that class’s spell list.
>
> In addition, choose one 1st-level spell from that same list. You learn
> that spell and can cast it at its lowest level. Once you cast it, you
> must finish a long rest before you can cast it again.
>
> Your spellcasting ability for these spells depends on the class you
> chose: Charisma for bard, sorcerer, or warlock; Wisdom for cleric or
> druid; or Intelligence for wizard.

Choosing Magic Initiate will open up spells without the need to dip into a class. A Cleric spell initiate may choose *Spare the Dying* and *Guidance* as cantrips and *Cure Wounds* or *Healing Word* as a 1st Level Spell.

- Spare the dying will allow your fighter to stabilise creatures
  without a medicine check nor healer's kit.
- Guidance is a support spell that boosts an allies ability check by
  1d4.
- Healing word is a ranged heal spell that uses up a bonus action and
  spell slot.
- Cure Wounds is a stronger heal spell but requires an action and has a
  range of touch.

### Fighter Class Options

**"Purple Dragon Knight/Banneret"** from SCAG pg 128.

This archetype available to knights at level 3 has the following feature that provides an AOE heal for your party:

> **Rallying Cry**
>
> When you choose this archetype at 3rd level, you learn how to inspire
> your allies to fight on past their injuries. When you use your Second
> Wind feature, you can choose up to three creatures within 60 feet of
> you that are allied with you. Each one regains hit points equal to
> your fighter level, provided that the creature can see or hear you.

A **"protection" fighting style** PHB pg 72 chosen at level 2 keeps with the theme of a shieldbearer/combat-medic type of fighter. She can protect her friends as she runs up to aid them.

> **Protection**
>
> When a creature you can see attacks a target other than you that is
> within 5 feet of you, you can use your reaction to impose disadvantage
> on the attack roll. You must be wielding a shield.

### Multiclass Options

Should you wish to multiclass your fighter either before or after level 4, these are some options available for a supporting healer *depending on her stats*. Keep in mind that multiclassing before level 4 restricts your access to feats. Note that multiclassing to/from/with fighter requires a minimum strength of 13.

- Paladin (Requires 13 STR and 13 CHA): Immediate access to Lay on Hands
- Druid (Requires 13 WIS): Access to healing word and cure wounds. Wild Shape / Summoning utility at later levels
- Bard (Requires 13 CHA): Access to healing word and cure wounds. Ability to buff allies and debuff enemies
- Life Cleric (Requires 13 WIS): Additional healing ability
- Grave Cleric (Requires 13 WIS): Ranged spare the dying. Maximised heal on creatures with 0 hit points.

Consider these options if your fighter doesn't have enough Charisma and Wisdom to multiclass into the above mentioned classes.

- Zealot Barbarian (Requires 13 STR): Requires 3 levels of barbarian but resurrection type spells can be cast on her for free if you ever need to revive her.
- Rogue Mastermind (Requires 13 DEX): Requires 3 levels of Rogue. Has ability to "help" when attacking at a range of 30 ft.
- Rogue Thief (Requires 13 DEX): Requires 3 levels of Rogue. Has *Fast Hands* which allows her to use items as a *Cunning Action*. This means you can feed potions up to twice per round and with action surge you may feed potions up to 3 times per round.

***Don't forget*** that you can always load up on healing potions and use an action to feed them to your ally. I've been in a game where a familiar doing just that prevented a TPK.  A fighter, aside from having better stats and standard actions than a familiar, also has action surge to feed potions twice if needed.

With all that said, I recommend you pick:

- *Variant human* with *4 levels in fighter*.
- Pick the *Purple Dragon Knight/Banneret* archetype
- *Protection* fighting style.
- *Inspiring Leader* and *Cleric Magic Initiate* Feats

After level 4, you may multiclass into one of these:

- Bard if she has high charisma
- Life Cleric if she has high wisdom
- Rogue Thief if she has high dex but low charisma and wisdom
- Zealot Barbarian if she has high strength but low charisma and wisdom

Good luck with your new Shield Maiden!

Comment: You mention quite a few options, and sometimes that's good, but to me it seems like this answer doesn't have that much guidance as to the *best* option, which is what the question was asking.

Answer (score 7):

### Without a doubt, if allowed, you want your Fighter to take a 1 level dip in Cleric (Grave domain).

Cleric: Guidance cantrip, Shield of Faith, **Healing Word**, Cure Light Wounds, Bless

But the real winner is this:

***XGtE p 19***

> **Circle of Mortality**
>
> At 1st level, you gain the ability to manipulate the line between life and death. When you would normally roll one or more dice to restore hit points with a spell to a creature at 0 hit points, you instead use the highest number possible for each die.
>
> In addition, you learn the ***Spare the Dying*** cantrip, which doesn't count against the number of cleric cantrips you know. For you, ***it has a range of 30 feet***, and you can ***cast it as a bonus action***.

*Okay maybe there is some room for argument.  Maybe Life Cleric is a little appealing for a few extra hp (although Grave does great if you are at 0).  But if you want an EMT sidekick, stabilizing from 30' away as a bonus action can't be beat.*

Comment: And eventually (Cleric 6), the Grave Domain gives "Sentinel at Death’s Door" or as I like to call it "CritNo". Being able to stop a critical hit from dealing extra damage is a very potent support ability.