# What are effective ways to revive a Zealot Barbarian?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-death

I was considering playing a Zealot Barbarian and was looking at the different ways that my character could be revived. Sure, there is the classic "lug a corpse around for the rest of the dungeon and all over til we find a cleric," but I was considering ways that might avoid having the party carry my weight, so to speak.

Are their magical items or something that might help in this endeavor? I want to be prepared, but I can't find much information.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the question here. Do you have reason to believe that reviving a Zealot Barb works differently than any other character? What methods have you looked into? You seem to have been playing 5e for a while, surely there are some methods you are already aware of - do you think those methods work or not on a Zealot? In other words, how is this question different from ["what are all the ways to revive a dead character?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120082/what-spells-are-available-to-resurrect-characters)

Comment: This might help you: [Which resurrection spells are valid to use with the Zealot's 'Warrior of the Gods' Feature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/150442/83286)

Comment: Related question on [What are effective ways for my fighter companion to heal me, a zealot barbarian?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/115104).

Comment: We can always reopen if the linked weren’t what you were asking about, but we’ll need to know how and why first.

Comment: @ThomasMarkovwasonStrike since Zealot Barbs don't require cost components to recieve revival spells, I was considering if there were other sources that could help him out and might avoid the spell slot cost for the party... like a Peiapt of Wound Closure but for reviving, or a consumable potion like a Pheonix Feather in video games. Sadly, all the links suggested offer the spells directly, requiring a spellcaster. If those are my only options, than I'm fine with that, but I thought it prudent to check my options first.

Comment: @NautArch-is-skeptical-about-SE as I just replied to Thomas, I was asking if there are things beyond having a spellcaster use up a spell slot. In the link you provided, there was talk about a healers kit that sounded like an interesting alternative, but I don't know if it can revive the Zealot...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148175/discussion-between-nautarch-is-skeptical-about-se-and-victor-b).